# Eclipse CDT - Makefile auto-update / refresh

Tags: c++, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on a simple C++ "Hello World" project with Eclipse CDT on CentOS. These are the files of the project in "src" folder:

- main.cpp
- hello.cpp
- hello.hpp

Eclipse CDT automatically generates build files in "Debug" folder:

- makefile
- objects.mk
- sources.mk
- src/subdir.mk

Contents of "Debug/src/subdir.mk":

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 
CPP_SRCS += \
../src/hello.cpp \
../src/main.cpp 

OBJS += \
./src/hello.o \
./src/main.o 

CPP_DEPS += \
./src/hello.d \
./src/main.d 


# Each subdirectory must supply rules for building sources it contributes
src/%.o: ../src/%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler'
    g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

I would like to launch the build not from Eclipse but from a terminal, using command line.

In the current situation, building with `make` (or with Eclipse) is working fine.
But if I modify the project (add / rename files...), building with command line doesn't work anymore, because **subdir.mk** - and all building files - **is not updated**.
The only way I found to update subdir.mk is to launch the build from Eclipse (or editing it manually...), which is not the way I want the project to be built.

So, is it possible to automatically update / refresh build files like subdir.mk, without building all the project?

Thank you :)

Comment: It looks to me that, if you modify the project as you said, you'll **have** to modify your Makefile (or the `subdir.mk` file, for that matter). Eclipse is doing exactly that behind the scenes for you, isn't it? You could generate these files using a script, but that seems overkill for this situation.

Comment: @faranwath Yes, Eclipse modify the Makefile but only before a build.

Comment: Like I said, you could have a script do the job, but I think it won't pay off for a "Hello, world" project.

Comment: Indeed, I'll think about it :)

Comment: That being said, I do recommend you to do this, but as a pure experiment in order to gain some insight into how build systems work.